# How can I diagnose what process is using CPU time? 

Tags: cpu, fan, cpu-load

It's a "problem" that i have since 11.10, now I've upgraded to 12.04 (fresh install).
Even while ondemand governor is set, and the computer is idle, fan goes on and doesn't want to shut down.

Images below:

[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9xCJ.png)

[processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVjHn.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up the terminal, do a

```
sudo apt-get install dstat
```

and type in:

```
dstat -c -y -l --proc-count --top-cpu
```

dstat is a system monitoring tool (like vmstat) and will show you the processes which consume the most CPU resources.

Comment: thanks ! it showed that no process is using CPU extensively. There's probably something wrong with GPU drivers ;/

Comment: With expanded arguments so you can see what they mean it's `dstat --cpu --sys --load --proc-count --top-cpu`. I find that adding a `--integer` helps as the single or double digits of the process CPU percent are easier to see. The line becomes `dstat --cpu --sys --load --proc-count --top-cpu --integer`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I had to **remove** the following boot-parameters (which I have added some months ago) to solve the problem:

```
pcie_aspm=force acpi=noirq
```